# Retrieving textarea from tabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea

I am trying to save the contents of a textarea that is on a panel inside a tabbed pane.

So far I have tried:

```
bw.write(tabbedPane.getComponent(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex()).toString());
```

and have been looking through all the methods for tabbedpane and I can not seem to work it out. I know I must get the selected component from the `tabbedPane`, then somehow get the textarea from that and then convert it to string I assume?

The code when I open a file is:

```
private void btnOpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (returnVal == fileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JTextArea x = new JTextArea();
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(x);
            p.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);            

            x.read( new FileReader( file.getAbsolutePath() ), null );
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            String name = selectedFile.getName();
            tabbedPane.add(p,name);
            tabbedPane.setSelectedComponent(p);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("problem accessing file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }
}
```

I have added the class as you insisted
Update Current SaveAs method:

```
private void btnSaveAsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);

    if (returnVal == fileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File dir1 = fileChooser.getCurrentDirectory();
        String dir = dir1.getPath();
        String name = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName() + ".txt";

        try {
            File file = new File(dir,name);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            JPanel no = (JPanel) tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();
            JTextArea bo = (JTextArea) no.get
            bw.write(bo.getText());
            bw.close();
            tabbedPane.setTitleAt(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex(), name);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

current open file method:

```
private void btnOpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (returnVal == fileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        try {
            FilePanel p = new FilePanel(file);
            tabbedPane.add(p,p.getName());
            tabbedPane.setSelectedComponent(p);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("problem accessing file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }
}
```

Do I need to add the new objects of the new class to an array or is it fine to just have them inserted to the tabbedPane?

Comment: Like I mentioned in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18422877/418556).  Post an SSCCE, copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: It might help if you included a little more of your actual code. perhaps where you created the text area and the tabs etc.

Comment: @leigero *"It might help if you included a little more of your actual code"*  The problem is usually that the OP has no idea what code is relevant and what is not.  An SSCCE fixes that.

Comment: @tbodt: why delete your answer? You deleted it before I could up-vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic here, but instead it's all how you code it. Your class that holds the JTextArea should have a public method, something like `getTextArea()` that returns the JTextArea. Then when you get the selected tab's component via `getSelectedComponent()`, you call this method on the component returned.

---

**Edit**
Based on the code you've posted, you need to re-think your program design. Your JTextArea is a local variable and thus not easily accessible, and there-in lies your problem.  I suggest:

- First and foremost, stop using Swing code-generator software, at least not until you understand the basics of Java and Swing as it will prevent you from gaining this understanding.
- Go through the Java and Swing tutorials to learn how to code Swing by hand.
- If you need access to specific components, be sure that they are class fields, and either they are accessible via getter methods, or even better that only the specific properties of the components of interest are accessible. For instance, if you want the text held in a JTextArea, rather than have a `getTextArea()` method that returns the JTextArea, have a `getTextAreaText()` that just returns the text held by the JTextArea. The more limited your code is to outside perturbations and side effects, the better.

  ---

**Edit 2**
For example, you could create a class that holds the JTextArea in a JPanel, something like:

```
class FilePanel extends JPanel {

   private File file;
   private JTextArea textArea;
   private String name;

   public FilePanel(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      this.file = file;
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      textArea = new JTextArea();
      JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
      add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      textArea.read(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()), null);
      name = file.getName();
   }

   public File getFile() {
      return file;
   }

   public JTextArea getTextArea() {
      return textArea;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

}
```

And then whenever you get the selectedComponent from the JTextPane, make sure it's not null, cast it to FilePanel and call getTextArea() on it.

---

**Edit 3**
For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FooSwing extends JFrame {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 450;
   private JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
   private JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

   public FooSwing() {
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
      btnPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Open") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnOpenActionPerformed(e);
         }
      }));
      btnPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Get Selected Text") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            FilePanel selectedComp = (FilePanel)tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();
            if (selectedComp != null) {
               String text = selectedComp.getTextArea().getText();
               System.out.println(text);
            } else {
               System.out.println("No component selected");
            }
         }
      }));

      add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private void btnOpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

      int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

      if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
         File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

         try {
            JPanel filePanel = new FilePanel(file);

            tabbedPane.add(filePanel, filePanel.getName());
            tabbedPane.setSelectedComponent(filePanel);
         } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("problem accessing file"
                  + file.getAbsolutePath());
         }
      } else {
         System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShow();
         }
      });
   }

   private static void createAndShow() {
      FooSwing fooSwing = new FooSwing();
      fooSwing.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      fooSwing.pack();
      fooSwing.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      fooSwing.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class FilePanel extends JPanel {

   private File file;
   private JTextArea textArea;
   private String name;

   public FilePanel(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      this.file = file;
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      textArea = new JTextArea();
      JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
      add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      textArea.read(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()), null);
      name = file.getName();
   }

   public File getFile() {
      return file;
   }

   public JTextArea getTextArea() {
      return textArea;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

}
```

Comment: I did everything, but I still cannot access the method getTextArea unless I do: FilePanel no = (FilePanel) tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();
        JTextArea bo = (JTextArea) no.getTextArea(); and it throws an error: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JPanel cannot be cast to texteditor.FilePanel

Comment: @Steve: don't copy my code. Copy my ideas, write your own code, and it will likely work.

Comment: @Steve: also believe what the error messages are telling you. If it gives you an error stating that you're trying to cast a general JPanel as something else, then you are in fact doing that -- trying to cast a JPanel as something else, and the solution is to not do that.

Comment: I understand, but what I am trying to do is access the current selected tab, and call the getTextArea method on that, but I do not know how to go about this. I am doing this for a college side-project:)

Comment: @Steve: I've explained how. You must fill the JTabbedPane with custom class objects, and then I've shown you an example. You're not yet doing this, so I don't know how I can further help you.

Comment: In your example you do:  FilePanel no = (FilePanel) tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();
It does not let me cast.

Comment: @Steve: do you see how my last code example is a complete compilable and runnable program, one that you can run, modify and test without alteration? That is an [sscce](http://sscce.org) and is something you should create, but with yours have it be one that demonstrates your problem. If we can reproduce your problem, we can understand it. Otherwise we'll only be able to guess.

Comment: Working at last =) thanks and sorry for being a pain! Now onto auto adding line breaks :P